# How to prevent XSS in data binding expression in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, xss, secure-coding

I am working on a project that security tools detects xss vulnerability on below code

```
            <asp:DataList ID="lstForums" SkinID="lstForums2" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>       
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Then to resolve that I added `HttpUtility.EncodeHtml` as below

```
<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description"))%>
```

but result of security scan is still same, How should I make that code xss proof?

Note: when I remove that line, security scan will pass

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but you have an extra `)` in your binding towards the end by `Decription"))`. Anyways, can you try this `<%# Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description"))%>`, does it work out? You need to make sure to import `System.Web.Security.AntiXss` namespace.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks, that was typo ;) , since the project is .net 4 AntiXSS is not there, I need to add it by nuget package which I am not allowed to

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer if someone else has same issue,

Although `HttpUtiltiy.EncodeHtml` and `Server.EncodeHtml` doing the same thing, the security tool (checkmarx) onlly consider `Server.EncodeHtml` as preventing code for XSS.

### using HttpUtility

[image]

### using Server

[image]

Comment: Interesting, both will not stop injected script from executing, it does cover some, but not all vectors. What `security tool` are you using?

Comment: @Reza not entirely true. checkmarx also considers AntiXss.HtmlEncode, Encoder.HtmlEncode, HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode, AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode, WebUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ see attached screen shots